# Confirm dialog onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, confirm

Hi I have read lots of other posts on the subject but am still confused. I just want to achieve 2 simple things before my page is unloaded.

1. If there is any unsaved data save it. Ask yes/no to save it (using confirm())
2. Save current selections on the page

I am doing it as follows.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {


    var model = _selectedClassNodes + ";" + _selectedIndicatorNodes + ";" + _selectedNode + ";" + _pageHeaderId;

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveDefaultSettings", "Maps")",
        type: 'get',
        data: { defaultSettings: model },
        success: function (data) {


        }
    });

    //if some unsaved data exists
    if (editedRows.length > 0) {

        if (confirm("Do you wish to save changes before continuing? CLick 'OK' for 'Yes' and 'Cancel' for 'No'")) {
            SaveGridData();
        }
    }


};
```

The **SaveDefaultSettings** is always fired as i have debugged with a break point but no confirm box appears.

As far as I remember confirm() was working ok before but today I noticed it has stopped working. I am using chrome v 62.0

If I change my code to

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

    return "Do you wish to save changes before continuing? CLick 'OK' for 'Yes' and 'Cancel' for 'No'";

    var model = _selectedClassNodes + ";" + _selectedIndicatorNodes + ";" + _selectedNode + ";" + _pageHeaderId;

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveDefaultSettings", "Maps")",
        type: 'get',
        data: { defaultSettings: model },
        success: function (data) {



        }
    });
 };
```

Instead now a default dialog says "Changes you made may not be saved" Reload/Don't Reload

Comment: You can't use any blocking code like alert or confirm in beforeunload. Over the years it was abused so much browser vendors had to limit it's capabilities...even to the extent of not displaying custom messages in most browsers

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

> If a string is assigned to the returnValue Event property, a dialog
>   appears asking the user for confirmation to leave the page (see
>   example below). Some browsers display the returned string in the
>   dialog box, but others display their own message.

That is why I am seeing a different message instead of the one I am returning.

The point that I mentioned it was working before was a confusion because same confirm dialog message is being used at another button click too.

My final code is

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {


    var model = _selectedClassNodes + ";" + _selectedIndicatorNodes + ";" + _selectedNode + ";" + _pageHeaderId;

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveDefaultSettings", "Maps")",
        type: 'get',
        data: { defaultSettings: model },
        success: function (data) {



        }
    });

    //if some unsaved data exists
    if (editedRows.length > 0) {
        return "There are some changes in grid data. You need to click 'Save Changes' or 'Cancel Changes' button on grid before continuing.";
    }


};
```